# C++ minimum element in vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm trying to find the minimum, non-zero distance in a vector. So I use the below code

```
vector<double> smallest_dist; 
for (int i = 0; i < dist.size(); i++) {
    while (dist.at(i) > 0){
        smallest_dist.push_back(dist.at(i));
    }
}
auto smallest = std::min_element(std::begin(smallest_dist), std::end(smallest_dist));
std::cout<<"smallest"<<*smallest<<endl;
cout<<"\n\n\n";
```

I go through a vector with a list of distances that has zero in it and pushback the distances at `i` so long as they're greater than 0 into a new vector `smallest_dist;`.

Then I try to use `std::min_element` to find the minimum element in that vector of doubles.

It gives me an iterator error. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Make sure `smallest_dist` is not empty.

Comment: Isn't the `while` an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2):

As

```
while (dist.at(i) > 0){
    smallest_dist.push_back(dist.at(i));
}
```

would be an infinite loop if there actually was some element greater than 0 in `dist`, but you do reach the output code, we can conclude that `smallest_dist` is empty.

Thus, `std::min_element` will return `std::end(smallest_dist)` and you cannot dereference that.

Instead, the `while` should be an `if` and the call to `std::min_element` should be preceded by some error check that asserts `smallest_dist` is not empty.

---

Remark: You do not actually need the handcrafted loop, you can use [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to gather all positive elements:

```
std::vector<double> smallest_dist;
std::copy_if(std::begin(dist), std::end(dist),
    std::back_inserter(smallest_dist), [](const auto &v){return v > 0;});

if (smallest_dist.empty()) {
    // No distance greater than 0, do error handling
}
```

Comment: hi, i tried using your method but still getting the same error message, and does not allow auto.

Comment: @EmperorElliott Did you make sure `smallest_dist` is not empty before calling `std::min_element` as I wrote? If yes, post a new question including a [mcve]. This answer addresses all issues with the code you posted above.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop. Replace `while` with `if`.